# What were the relative orientations of the Hubble Space Telescope's three star cameras, six rate gyros and four reaction wheels optimized for exactly?

Tags: attitude-determination-and-control, camera, reaction-wheel, hubble, gyroscope

Table 3. in paper [Hubble Space Telescope Reduced-Gyro Control Law Design, Implementation and On-Orbit Performance; AAS 08-278](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20080023344.pdf) found in [@OrganicMarble's answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/42044/12102) seems to give the unit vectors where the HST's three star cameras (Fixed Head Star Tracker's or FHST's) point:

```
FHST Num.     t1         t2        t3
    1       0.0000     0.0000    -1.0
    2      -0.6547    -0.3779     0.6546
    3      -0.6547     0.3779     0.6546
```

and Table 1 there gives the axes of the six rate-measuring gyroscopes.

```
Gyro Number   g1         g2        g3
    1     -0.52547    0         -0.85081
    2     -0.52547    0          0.85081
    3     -0.58566   -0.61716   -0.52547
    4      0.58566    0.61716   -0.52547
    5     -0.58566    0.61716   -0.52547
    6      0.58566   -0.61716   -0.52547
```

I haven't found a table for the orientation of the four momentum control gyroscopes but the image shown below suggests that they are at

```
+sin(20)   +cos(20)sin(45)   cos(20)cos(45)
+sin(20)   -cos(20)sin(45)   cos(20)cos(45)
-sin(20)   +cos(20)sin(45)   cos(20)cos(45)
-sin(20)   -cos(20)sin(45)   cos(20)cos(45)
```

or

```
 0.342020     0.66446     0.66446
 0.342020    -0.66446     0.66446
-0.342020     0.66446     0.66446
-0.342020    -0.66446     0.66446
```

[This comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/42039/12102) suggests that (at least for the camera directions) the directions are the way they are because

> It works with the practicalities of the design, and it's good enough.

While this is likely to be true, I have a hunch some serious thought and design optimization went into the decision where to point all of these things.

**Question:** How were the orientations of the Hubble Space Telescope's Star cameras, rate gyros and reaction wheels (3+6+4=13) optimized to work together in a coordinated way? How were the merit functions (for lack of a better word) chosen? What exactly was optimized?

---

From [Three Axis Control of the Hubble Space Telescope Using Two Reaction Wheels and Magnetic Torquer Bars for Science Observation, AAS 08-279](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20080023343.pdf)

[image: Figure 1 Reaction wheel assembly configuration]

> Figure 1 Reaction wheel assembly configuration

Here are the values in Python along with a plot. I tried taking the dot products of various combinations but didn't find any obvious interrelationships right away.

[image: a bunch of vectors]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

degs = 180/np.pi
camvecs = np.array([[0, 0, -1],
                 [-0.6547, -0.3779, -0.6546],
                 [-0.6547, +0.3779, -0.6546]])

rategyrovecs = np.array([[-0.52547,  0,       -0.85081],
                     [-0.52547,  0,        0.85081],
                     [-0.58566, -0.61716, -0.52547],
                     [ 0.58566,  0.61716, -0.52547],
                     [-0.58566,  0.61716, -0.52547],
                     [ 0.58566, -0.61716, -0.52547]])

sin20, cos20 = [f(20*np.pi/180) for f in (np.sin, np.cos)]
sin45, cos45 = [f(45*np.pi/180) for f in (np.sin, np.cos)]

controlgyrovecs = np.array([[+sin20, +cos20 * sin45, cos20 * cos45],
                            [+sin20, -cos20 * sin45, cos20 * cos45],
                            [-sin20, +cos20 * sin45, cos20 * cos45],
                            [-sin20, -cos20 * sin45, cos20 * cos45]])

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[10, 8])  # [12, 10]
ax  = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
for x, y, z in camvecs:
    ax.plot([-x, x], [-y, y], [-z, z], '-k', linewidth=2)
for x, y, z in rategyrovecs:
    ax.plot([-x, x], [-y, y], [-z, z], '-r')
for x, y, z in controlgyrovecs:
    ax.plot([-x, x], [-y, y], [-z, z], '-b')
ax.set_xlim(-1.1, 1.1)
ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1)
ax.set_zlim(-1.1, 1.1)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a real answer, but some thoughts that are too long for a comment

I doubt there was a concern about optimizing the directions for easier calculations. 
Positions are fixed and known, so all equations can be "hand-crafted" to allow for rather quick but still precise calculations in the on-board computers.

The orientation of the 4 reaction wheels seems rather straight forward to me.
In the ideal case of four momentum wheels you would orient them like the faces of a regular tetrahedron - in this way any of them can fail while the other three combined can induce a momentum in the direction of the failed wheels axis.
But this only applies for a symmetric satellite. The elongated tube shape of Hubble is far from that. You need a lot more torque to rotate around the $v_2$ and $v_3$ axes compared to $v_1$. Exactly this is accomplished by separating the wheels by 90° in the 2-3-plane but by only 40° degrees perpendicular to it. In this way the sum of torque generated by the four wheels can be twice as high when tilting the whole telescope compared to a rotation around the bore-sight axis.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is definitely food for though! When I looked at the linked [Reduced-Gyro Control Law](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20080023344.pdf) paper I noticed the sentence fragment "..the linearized FGS attitude error equations were sufficient, and implementing the non-linear spherical trigonometric star vector equations was avoided in the original DF-224 flight computer, having limited processing power. " which made me wonder if these orientations might have been chosen to make the calculation less costly somehow (though FGS is something different).

Comment: I lost track of the bounty so it has auto-awarded at 50%, I should have caught it at the last minute and awarded it all since this contains *plenty of helpful insight.*