# Is it possible to control the operation of the Hubble Space Telescope from ground stations?

Tags: space-telescope, telescope, hubble, mission-control, enviromental-control-system

Is it possible to manage the placement of the telescope mirror in a specific location through the operator, or do we have to randomly view the data reflected to the telescope ?

Comment: Are you asking if the telescope is left uncontrolled and tumbling and we only take random shots?

Comment: Yes , thank you for comment

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bhubble%5D+attitude

Comment: @Polygnome Well a layperson might assume that the Hubble telescope is simply static in space or static in orbit (so not "uncontrollably tumbling") and because there aren't any visible rockets or jets or ion-drives on the Hubble that it must therefore require some astronauts to physically go out there and manually adjust it by-hand. (In reality it uses Reaction Wheels and Magnetic Torquers - but I imagine most people in the world have no idea how RWs and MTs work because rotational movement without a reaction-mass in-space is not something most people think about, I assume).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What were the relative orientations of the Hubble Space Telescope's three star cameras, six rate gyros and four reaction wheels optimized for exactly?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/42061/what-were-the-relative-orientations-of-the-hubble-space-telescopes-three-star-c)

Comment: This is a pretty weak question.  Do you really think a billion-dollar project would be left to random chance operation?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft knowing about the specifics of Hubble, this would certainly be absurd – but just from the fact that it's a billion-dollar space telescope this isn't so evident. For a survey telescope like Gaia, “random tumbling” could still be useful enough, in fact this _is_ basically what Gaia does (the properties of the rotation are well controlled, but there's never an input like “now point the telescope toward that particular spot”).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, Hubble is actively controlled from the ground.

See [this NASA page on Hubble Mission Operations](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/hubble/mission-operations)

> Examples include monitoring and adjusting the spacecraft’s subsystems (e.g., power, thermal, data management, **pointing control**, etc.), flight software development, sustaining engineering of the control center hardware and software, and systems administration of the network and ground system components.
>   (Highlight mine)

Images taken with Hubble are carefully planned. The telescope must be pointed in the right direction and hold this attitude for a prolonged time.

Compare for example [the Hubble Deep Fields](https://www.spacetelescope.org/science/deep_fields/).

> The first Deep Field, the Hubble Deep Field North (HDF-N), was observed over 10 consecutive days during Christmas 1995. The resulting image consisted of 342 separate exposures, with a total exposure time of more than 100 hours, compared with typical Hubble exposures of a few hours

The telescope does hold the programmed attitude on its own. A good overview over the way the Hubble holds attitude is given here:

[Hubble - Observatory - Pointing Control](https://www.nasa.gov/content/goddard/hubble-space-telescope-pointing-control-system)

Basically, the desired attitude for an image is carefully calculated on the ground. The attitude is then sent up to the telescope, as well as the instruction for what images to take and how long. The telescope then controls itself, rotates to the programmed attitude and takes the pre-programmed shots. It has fail-safes to ensure that it never points at the sun, which could damage the telescope.

Comment: Thank you for your beautiful and complete explanation, for example, can we point it to Mars and see the curiosity of the Curiosity Rover through it ?

Comment: That would make a great new question, @Merlin.

Comment: @Merlin No, we can not. We can#t even see stuff left on the moon with Hubble, see this Q&A: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12347/picture-of-equipment-left-on-the-moon